# Standardize the construction of the object Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, software-design

I have two java classes

Job

```
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String status;
```

Workflow

```
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String Status;
    public Date nextDate();
    public String type;
```

I would like to build a method that builds a Workflow type object with Job characteristics

```
public Workflow buildWorkflow(Job job){

Workflow test = new Workflow();

test.setId(job.getId());
test.setName(job.getName())
test.setStatus(job.getStatus());

test.setNetDate(new Date());
test.setType("java");

return test;
}
```

how can i standardize the construction of the object if the object changes?

JobStandard

```
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String status;
```

I should completely rewrite the method:

```
public Workflow buildWorkflow(JobStandard jobstandard){

Workflow test = new Workflow();

test.setId(jobstandard.getId());
test.setName(jobstandard.getName())
test.setStatus(jobstandard.getStatus());

test.setNetDate(new Date());
test.setType("java");

return test;
}
```

Tips ?

Comment: Why not make your `Workflow` have an `ArrayList<Job>` parameter? Or the other way around. Make your Job have an `ArrayList<Workflow>`

Comment: The `buildWorkflow` method can depend on an abstraction rather than a concrete class. `Job` and `JobStandard` can both implement this abstraction.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want `Workflow` to subclass `Job`? It seems like a `Workflow` **is-a** `Job` with two more fields. And if `Job` changes, you want `Workflow` to change.

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite the method? The only thing that changes is the class name of the buildWorkflow input, no need to change the name you give to the input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A typical case of polymorphism.
First you'll have to think about a generic model that you'll want to the workflow to handle.

For example

```
interface Job
     String getJobId();
     String getJobName();
     String getJobStatus();
```

Now, you can use different implementations of `Job`

```
GenericJob implements Job
SpecialisedJob implements Job
VeryCustomJob implements Job
```

and all of these will have to implement the interface's methods.

Alternatively you can use an AbstractClass that has the same methods defined.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using composition rather than copying values or extension.  That is, make the Job a component of the Workflow.  You don't copy the values of the Job - you attach the Job associated with that Workflow.

```
public class Job {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String status;
  ....
}

public class Workflow {
  private Job job;
  private Date date;
  private String type;
  ....
}
```